# Regex to find qualified variable use

Tags: java, regex

I am currently attempting to create a regex that will match whenever there is qualified variable use
For Example :

```
    int foo = foofoo.bar;
```

Returns **foofoo.bar**

```
    foo.method(foobar.bar);
```

will return **foobar.bar**

My current approach is to use this regex

```
    [\w]*[.][\w]*<(?!\()
```

Where it matches the classname, the period, the public variable then finally specifies that it is not followed by a bracket (to differentiate it from method calls) with

At the moment it the part checking the final bracket doesn't seem to be working, and would appreciate any help!

Comment: not sure about the java regex flavor but the < before the lookahead seems odd. also, you could simply negate a character class for the brackets, `\w+\.\w+[^(]` would be my approach

Comment: Are you sure that this is a good approach. What if you are forced to use fully qualified names?..

Comment: @DesertEagle seems on track. But I would also take into account the possibility of white space being inserted at various points - `\w+\s*\.\s*\w+\s*[^(]`. Otherwise `foo.method (foobar.bar);` would return both `foo.method` **and** `foobar.bar`.

Comment: as a first hint: replace < by a + in your regex

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestion!
and @DesertEagle you make a good point, however in this situation I only need to be concerned with this case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution:

```
\b[^\W\d]\w*(?:\s*\.\s*[^\W\d]\w*\b)+(?!\s*\()
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tK3dW5/2) (PCRE example but applicable here since the features I used are available in Java as well).

Use word boundaries (`\b`), to ensure you match whole words, and also make sure you can handle whitespace (`\s*`).

`[^\W\d]\w*` is like `\w+` except it disallows a digit as the first character.

This is **not** a robust solution though, you'll also find qualified names in comments and strings for instance. If you need something better, use a proper parser.

Comment: For my use case I need to also be able to find it in comments and strings as well, so it works perfectly! Thank you :)

Comment: I forgot to mention: you should add something like `(?!\d)` at the beginning to avoid matching floating point values like `42.00` for instance. Or replace *each* `\w+` with `[^\W\d]\w*` - that would be more correct.